# Get product code from text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the product code from a string without VBA, for example:

1. `this is product KAK 8732`
2. `this is product YUI 889`
3. `this is product SM 001`

I want to get product code:

1. `KAK 8732`
2. `YUI 889`
3. `SM 001`

please help, thank you

Comment: You really need to tell us the rules of the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",60)),120))
```

or

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1))+1,255)
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi,  I dont understand, please spesific

Comment: Hi, thank you, it work and usefull, can u tell me what is REPT use for? I never seen before

Comment: @HengkyST - `REPT` function repeats characters a given number of times. For details see [this](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-rept-function).

Answer (score 1):

=SUBSTITUTE("this is product KAK 8732","this is product ","")

Comment: Hi, the title text not always "this is product", this just example